# How to display spreadsheet style result on screen

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a result set of a class in List Results; format

```
public class Result
{
 public string StudentName {get; set;}
 public string Subject {get; set;}
 public string Marks {get; set;}
}
```

so i want to display it in Spreadsheet style like this.

[image]

What should be best approach to display it on MVC View?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Subjects <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right pull-right"></span></th>
            @foreach (var sub in subjects)
            {
                <th>@sub</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in students)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item</td>
                @for (int i = 0; i < subjects.Count(); i++)
                {
                     var etc = Model.FirstOrDefault(m => m.StudentName == item && m.Subject == subjects.ElementAt(i));
                    <td>@etc.Marks</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note subjects and students are distinct() values from model

Comment: Theres not really enough to go on here, I mean are you passing some sort of collection to your view? Have you tried anything? If so please add it to your answer, so we can be clearer about what you are aiming for. I mean is there anything wrong with an HTML table with some CSS, or potentiall use MVC Grid http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/597253/Using-the-Grid-MVC-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: yes, i think i have a way to get marks, you can see the update. i posted question here to know if there are good way or some tools?

Comment: I don't see anything intrinsically wrong with your approach, I mean it works doesn't it.